# Misaligned inline block elements with variable heights

Tags: html, css

I have code like:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <p>Testing</p>
      <p>Testing</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <p>Testing</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.item {
  background: orange;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I noticed things are ok when the inline blocks have same content. But why when they have different heights, does it become misaligned?

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/jiewmeng/pen/xbEWOL)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to `.item` not the `.container`, it applies to inline-level and table-cell elements . You could use `vertical-align: middle` to vertically center the elements.

Examples on different `vertical-align` values [here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html) should make things clear.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.item {
  background: orange;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Testing</p>
    <p>Testing</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Testing</p>
  </div>
</div>
```